# Not able to compile with WEMOS D1

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I followed [this](https://www.instructables.com/Programming-the-WeMos-Using-Arduino-SoftwareIDE/) instructor to start with my Arduino.
As far as I try to do step number 13 (upload something) it returns:

> open NUL: The system cannot find the file specified.
> Error compiling for board LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 R2 & mini.

Comment: try in Boards Manager to remove (button Remove) the esp8266 platform and install it again

Comment: @Juraj I did before and I tried to install other versions but still dont work